# Transform rotate on hover shifting up one pixel

Tags: html, css

I have created a circle with a fontAwesome icon in it, and on hover, rotating it 180 degree that is working fine, But on hover when I mouseover and when icon moving to 180 its moving up by one pixel, not sure why.

My question is why its moving up by one pixel on hover, I'm not able to find the issue.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/yyuuczy8/5/) demo

**EDIT** Please note that its happening in Firefox only.

```css
.share-icon {
background-color: #f00;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
color: #ffffff;
float: left;
font-size: 18px;
height: 45px;
line-height: 45px;
margin-top: 50px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 45px;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
cursor: pointer;
}
.share-icon:hover {
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="share-icon" onclick="shairIcon(this)">
  <i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: no its not moving up.. i could seee

Comment: I forgot to mention that its happening in FireFox only

Comment: No it is not moving. try adding translateY(-1px) to see what really happens if it moves one px.

Comment: adding translateY(-1px) doesnt fix the issue, its still moving..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this css, i have made correction.

You should add fa icon class on hover and add transition property.

```
.share-icon:hover .fa-share-alt {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

Working [DEMO!!!](https://jsfiddle.net/yyuuczy8/7/)

Comment: great, its working perfectly, making the rotation on icon instead of box is good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't know exactly why but if you increase your `font-size` just by two pixels you'll get rid of this jump. Simply update your code to the following

```css
.share-icon {
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.share-icon i {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.share-icon:hover i {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="share-icon" onclick="shairIcon(this)">
  <i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: font size is not the issue, issue was with rotation, I was rotating the main div but as suggested by @Logeshwaran rotating icon would fix problem that did as well.

Comment: @SanjeevK Ah okay, thought you meant that you didn't want the small jump of the icon after the hover animation was done. But yeah great that the previous answer could have solved your issue.